# "go to error" command sends me to an .fff file

Tags: errors, texshop

After typesetting a LaTeX document and seeing an error notice in the console, why does "Go To Error" command sends me to an .fff file?

Comment: Please, add a minimal code showing the error.

Comment: go to error does nothing (usually) or jumps to the error in the source if your editor is so configured to understand that, so it's entirely a question of editor configuration and you have not said which editor you use.

Comment: Thank you, folks!  i am using the internal TeXShop editor.  in the last 10 minutes i was trying to copy from the console without success.  tried to show you a picture of the console -- same.  i just updated TeXShop to version 3.43.

Comment: i would like "go to error" to send me to the place of the error, which was happening before the last update.

Comment: @evapetkova You need to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. And also add only a screenshot of the error you find in TeXshop instrad of copy that from the console, it is easier than what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Aradnix I don't think a MWE would help here (well you could have a file with just `\rubbishnotdefined` ) the question is about editor behaviour on getting any error

Comment: I added the texshop tag, sorry can't help further I have never used that editor.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well I asked for a MWE because I have the same editor and the screen shot to see what she gets when she tries to compile the document and compare in my own case and could help. I understand that for other uses the MWE couldn't work here.

Comment: @Aradnix OK,  perhaps:-)